# Exposing DNN sitemap to external asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-6

I am trying to expose the DNN6 Sitemap provider to an external asp.net application.

Does anyone have any useful tips for accomplishing this?

I can get user and tab properties with no problem; and created a node for the base URL in the asp.net application, help?

I created a DNN web service that my application will call to setup navigation properly on the asp.net legacy application (using DNN to maintain navigation and permissions).

Comment: Is the built-in site map any help? http://www.dotnetnuke.com/sitemap.aspx.

Comment: no, trying to expose this so i can provide navigation on another asp.net site. --

Comment: You are wanting to use the sitemap provider in another ASP.NET site - that is not DNN based. is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the full code of a handler that retrieves tabs in hierarchy from the DNN database and returns the result as an xml document. It's a child's play to wrap any sitemap provider around the xml.

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Menus" %>

using System;
using System.Web;


using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Globalization;

using DotNetNuke.Common;
using DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities;
using DotNetNuke.Entities.Portals;
using DotNetNuke.Entities.Tabs;
using DotNetNuke.Security.Permissions;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public class Menus : IHttpHandler {

public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {



string cc = PortalAliasController.GetPortalAliasByTab(Int32.Parse(context.Request.Params["tabid"]),"");

PortalAliasInfo pa = PortalAliasController.GetPortalAliasInfo(cc);
int portalid = pa.PortalID;


PortalSettings ps = new PortalSettings(portalid);
int tabid = ps.HomeTabId;  

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.Params["tabid"]))
    tabid = Int32.Parse(context.Request.Params["tabid"]);  


XmlWriterSettings ws = new XmlWriterSettings();
ws.Indent = true;
ws.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(context.Response.OutputStream, ws);
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";


xw.WriteStartElement("root");
xw.WriteElementString("portalid", portalid.ToString());


MakeMenu(context, xw, tabid, portalid);

xw.WriteEndElement();
xw.Close();


}

public bool IsReusable {
    get {
        return false;
    }
}


private void MakeMenu(HttpContext context, XmlWriter xw, Int32 tabid, Int32 portalid)
{



    List<TabInfo> tabs = TabController.GetTabsByParent(tabid, portalid);
    if (tabs.Count == 0) return;




    foreach (TabInfo objTab in tabs)
    {


        if (!objTab.IsDeleted &&
          !objTab.DisableLink &&
          objTab.IsVisible &&
          objTab.TabType == TabType.Normal &&
          (Null.IsNull(objTab.StartDate) || objTab.StartDate < DateTime.Now) &&
          (Null.IsNull(objTab.EndDate) || objTab.EndDate > DateTime.Now)

        )
        {
            if (TabPermissionController.CanViewPage(objTab))
            {


                string tabName = objTab.TabName;
                string URL = objTab.FullUrl;

              if (URL.ToLower().IndexOf(context.Request.Url.Host.ToLower()) == -1) ;

              URL = Globals.AddHTTP(context.Request.Url.Host) + URL;


              xw.WriteStartElement("menu");
              xw.WriteAttributeString("text", tabName);
              xw.WriteAttributeString("url", URL);
              MakeMenu(context, xw, objTab.TabID, portalid);
              xw.WriteEndElement();

            }

        }


    }


}
```

}